# KendoUI: TabStrip changing URL in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a KendoUI TabStrip defined like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
.Name("tabMain")
.Items(items =>
{
    items.Add().Text("Search/Manage User").Content("Some text");
    items.Add().Text("Create New User").Content("Some text");
})
.SelectedIndex(0)
.Animation(false)
)
```

When I select a tab, the URL of the page changes to **localhost/#TabMain-1** and the page scrolls to the tab.

How do I turn off that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already fixed. Stay tuned and wait until tomorrow - there will be new release :) the Q1 2013 !